# References on frequentist hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references

I am looking for some references on frequentist hypothesis testing (e.g., t-test, chi-squared test, F-test, A/B testing etc). I have significant experience with probabilistic methods like Bayes rules, GLRT, UMP etc from graduate inference courses, but it's been a long time since I studied the approaches that are based on a sample and not on a probabilistic model. Any advice for any good book or any good notes? I am looking for something relatively short that also explains the intuition behind the tests. Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking to learn from the references?

Comment: Basically trying to refresh some basic statistical tests, e.g., t-test, chi squared test, F-test, confidence intervals etc before a job interview.

Comment: [Degroot and Schervish](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/De-Groot-Probability-and-Statistics-4th-Edition/PGM146802.html). You can refer only chapter on hypothesis testing.

Answer (score 0):

I really like and recommend the following book: https://learningstatisticswithr.com/ it's well written and free.